# Fire and event after the user is logged in for certain amount of time

Tags: php, laravel

I know how to handle **events** and listeners in Laravel, but my question is, how to fire and event when a user is logged in for more than 90 minutes. 
Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Laravel 5.3 you can override `login()` method in `LoginController.php` and save timestamp of the moment when user logged in.

Then you could run Scheduler task each minute and get all users who logged in 90 minutes ago and fire event.

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a job and delay it.

check this link for more information :

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queues#delayed-dispatching

Comment: If this job checks if the user is still logged in, then maybe.